# How to setup Kafka with SSL and ACL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I'm stuck with a setting up an ACL for Kafka. I'm running Kafka in Docker with this docker compose:

```
version: "2"
networks:
  kafka-network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.5.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: zookeeper
    user: root
    networks:
        - kafka-network
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_AUTOPURGE_PURGE_INTERVAL: 24
        ZOOKEEPER_AUTOPURGE_SNAP_RETAIN_COUNT: 5
    volumes:
      - ./zoo/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: kafka
    user: root
    depends_on:
        - zookeeper
    ports:
        - "9092:9092"
    networks:
        - kafka-network
    environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: SSL://:9092,PLAINTEXT://:9093
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://<host ip>:9092,PLAINTEXT://kafka:9093
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: false
        KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: broker.keystore.jks
        KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: pass
        KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: pass
        KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: broker.truststore.jks
        KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: pass
        KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: requested
        KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
        KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
        KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: requested
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: true
        KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
        KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: true
        KAFKA_SUPER_USERS: "User:CN=localhost,CN=root"
    volumes:
        - ./secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
        - ./kafka/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

My services connect to kafka via SSL, this part works fine. Now I'm trying to add super user - I created certificate with a CN=root and added KAFKA_SUPER_USERS: "User:CN=root" parameter, but when I tried to list ACL with command
`docker exec kafka kafka-acls --bootstrap-server=localhost:9092 --list --command-config=/etc/kafka/secrets/root.properties`
I was getting an error
`No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found`
This is my root.properties:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/broker.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=pass
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/root.keystore
ssl.keystore.password=pass
ssl.key.password=pass
```

There is CA certificate in the broker.truststore, and my root certificate + ca in the root.keystore.

I tried to add localhost to CN - now my certificate subject looks like "CN=localhost,CN=root" - but still get this error. Also, as I read, parameter KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: "" must disable host verification. Why I still get this error? Maybe it's possible some way to setup all outer connections with SSL and leave admin access through localhost without certificates?